# How to change Spinner look to dropdown in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to know how to change the look of spinner like drop down programmatically. My spinner is created dynamically. I want something like this (see the image spinner below):-

[image]

but i get this type of view:-

[image]

My Spinner code:-

```
  Spinner spinnerQty = new Spinner(ProductsDetails.this);
                List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
                qty.add(getResources().getString(R.string.Select_qty));

                for(int i=1;i<=Integer.parseInt(productsdata_qty);i++){
                    qty.add(String.valueOf(i));
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapterQty = new ArrayAdapter<>(ProductsDetails.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,qty );
                spinnerQty.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterQty);
                product_details_outer_linerar_layout.addView(spinnerQty);
```

Comment: Use Device which runs on API level before 4.0. Why you need only the old UI?

Comment: No I want using API level 16+

Answer (score 1):

Use another constructor:

```
Spinner spinnerQty = new Spinner(ProductsDetails.this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
```